# How can i link acf google map post lat and long with mapbox?

Tags: wordpress, mapbox, advanced-custom-fields

I'm looking for a way to use the coordinates of all my posts? created with **acf** **google map field)**? and display them as markers in a mapbox map?

Does someone already done this?

Can anyone can explain me the logic to create this??

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. There are plenty of tutorials showing you how to do exactly this. Do you have any code you can show where you have already tried utilizing the maps?

An abstract explanation is to basically loop trough all your posts and add the lat and long's as a data attribute to an element. In your JS you query all the elements, get the data attributes and put the data in an array or arrays like so: `var markers = [
        ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
        ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
    ];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question. There are plenty of tutorials showing you how to do exactly this. Do you have any code you can show where you have already tried utilizing the maps?

An abstract explanation is to basically loop trough all your posts and add the lat and long's as a data attribute to an element:

```
<div class="marker" data-lat="<?php get_field('location_lat', id) ?>" data-lng="<?php get_field('location_lng', id) ?>" data-title="<?php get_field('location_title', id) ?>"></div>
```

In your JS (assuming you're using jQuery) you query all the elements, get the data attributes and put the data in an array or arrays like so:

```
var getMarkers = $('.marker');
var markers = [];

getMarkers.each(function(index, marker) {
  markers.push([marker.data('title'), marker.data('lat'), marker.data('lng')])
});
```

This variable can in turn be used by maps to loop through and place the markers. See: https://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/

I hope this helps you in the right direction!

Comment: Thank you for your help, it points me to the right direction ! I finaly got it, and create stunning interactive map. You can see an example here : https://www.virtual-trip.fr/asie/philippines/. The markers are not shown in my map, but scrolling the page moves the page to the right coordinates.